# Matching an XPath expression against a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, evaluate

I have XML content that I need to query from within javascript.  To use a simple example, here is the XML:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <author>Smith, John</author>
    <subject>Science Fiction</subject>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>DEF</title>
    <author>Jones, Tom</author>
    <subject>Biography</subject>
  </book>
</books>
```

This XML is referenced in an 'xmlDoc' variable.

Now I want to find all  nodes where the  child node is equal to a value passed in via a URL parameter, or some other dynamically selected method.  This category is stored in a variable called 'category'.

I can create an evaluate expression like:

```
var result = xmlDoc.evaluate('/books/book[category="Biography"]', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult. ANY_TYPE,null);
```

if I statically enter the category value.

But how do I check if the value of the  node matches the value of the 'category' variable?  I likely need to escape the 'category' variable in some way, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Am I missing something or why would you not just use `'/books/book[category="' + category + '"]'`?

Comment: you're not missing anything.  But apparently I am, my brain. :)  Sorry, I was looking for something more complex when the answer was straightforward.  thanks!

Comment: @t0mppa you should add that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Added, it just seemed like a too simple question and thus would have a catch. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you would [concatenate Strings normally in JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#conc). That is by using the `+` operation:

```
var result = xmlDoc.evaluate('/books/book[category="' + category + '"]',
                             xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```